# Get a wildcard instance from Google Guice

Tags: java, guice

Hi I am experimenting with `Google Guice 5.x`. I have my class defined as:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    // some logic here
}
```

and it's being used in other classes like:

```
public class Bar {

    private final Foo<Chocolate> provider;

    public Bar(Foo<Chocolate> _choco) {
        this.provider = _choco;
    }
}


public abstract class BaseZoo { // in some other package in a different jar

    private final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyAppModule());

    private Foo<?> provider;

    public String doSomething() {

        if (provider == null)
            this.provider = this.injector.getInstance(Foo.class);

        // some other code logic.
    } 
}
```

Now, in my module file *(`MyAppModule`)* I have defined Foo as:

```
@Inject
@Provides
@Singleton
public Foo<Chocolate> getFoo(FooDependency fooDep) {
    return new Foo<>(fooDep);
}
```

---

Now when I run my code, Google Guice is able to find an instance for `Foo<Chocolate>` but is not able to find an instance for `Foo<?>`.

Is there a way to configure Google Guice to resolve `Foo<?>` with an instance of `Foo<Chocolate>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the type:

```
@Inject
@Provides
@Singleton
public Foo<?> getFoo(FooDependency fooDep) { ... }
```

If you still want to bind `Foo<Chocolate>`, use the `@Provides` method in the question, but also bind `Foo<?>` to it, you can do so in your configure method:

```
bind(new Key<Foo<?>>() {}).to(new Key<Foo<Chocolate>>() {});
```

or, with a provider method:

```
@Provides
Foo<?> provideWildcardFoo(Foo<Chocolate> chocolateFoo) {
  return chocolateFoo;
}
```

Comment: You mean have two definitions, one for `Foo<?>` and another for `Foo<Chocolate>`?

Comment: If you want a binding to `Foo<?>`, you have to have a binding to `Foo<?>` specifically. I don't know what your requirements are beyond that.

Comment: Both approaches work for me tbh. I was just curious about why it wasn't working until I noticed there are three different types being asked of Guice `Foo<Chocolate>`, `Foo<?>` and `Foo` so doing a injector.getIntance(Foo.class) is actually looking for a `Foo` and not a `Foo<?>`. Which is incorrect on my side because I actually need to get an instance of `Foo<?>` and not `Foo`. Thanks for the two approaches. +1